# Why won't spring autowire my test?

Tags: spring, autowired

I've got the following spring configuration (actually, the configuration is more extensive, but I've included relevant parts):

**testApplicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Business -->
<import resource="contexts/testBusinessContext.xml" />    

<!-- Dao -->
<import resource="contexts/testDaoContext.xml" />    

<!-- Persistence configuration -->
<import resource="contexts/testPersistenceContext.xml" />    

<!-- Service actions -->
<import resource="contexts/testServiceActionContext.xml" />
```

**testBusinessContext.xml**

```
<bean id="basketBusiness" class="com.company.salesdataservice.business.BasketBusiness">
    <property name="basketDao" ref="basketDao" />
    <property name="tokenDao" ref="tokenDao" />
    <property name="houseDao" ref="houseDao" />
    <property name="currencyDao" ref="currencyDao" />
</bean>
```

**testDaoContext.xml**

```
<bean id="currencyDao" class="com.company.salesdataservice.dao.CurrencyDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="companyDomainDataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="houseDao" class="com.company.salesdataservice.dao.HouseDao"/>
<bean id="basketDao" class="com.company.salesdataservice.dao.BasketDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="companyBookingDataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="tokenDao" class="com.company.salesdataservice.dao.JavaRandomTokenDao" />
```

**testPersistenceContext.xml**

```
<bean id="companyBookingTransactionManager" class="com.company.utils.data.TransactionManager">
    <property name="manager" ref="companyBookingSpringTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="companyBookingSpringTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="companyBookingDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- initialised by a DataSourceInitializer. Left out for brevity. -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="companyBookingDataSource" type="H2"/>

<!-- initialised by a DataSourceInitializer. Left out for brevity. -->    
<jdbc:embedded-database id="companyDomainDataSource" type="H2"/>
```

**testServiceActionContext.xml**

```
<bean id="createBasketServiceAction" class="com.company.salesdataservice.serviceaction.CreateBasketServiceAction">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="companyBookingTransactionManager" />
    <property name="basketBusiness" ref="basketBusiness" />
</bean>
```

I'm trying to autowire a field of the type `CreateBasketServiceAction` in one of my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class CreateBasketServiceActionTest {

    @Autowired
    CreateBasketServiceAction createBasketServiceAction;

}
```

However, Spring keeps telling me that it can't autowire:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.utils.data.serviceaction.TransactionalServiceAction] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

If i replace that field with a `BasketBusiness basketBusiness` field, then Spring is perfectly capable of doing it.

As far as I can see, both `CreateBasketServiceAction` and `BasketBusiness` is defined as a `<bean />` in the XML configuration.

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours on this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is there more in the stack trace? the error shows it's looking for TransactionalServiceAction.. what is the relation between CreateBasketServiceAction and TransactionalServiceAction?

Comment: Does the `CreateBasketServiceAction` have any reason to be proxied in your context configuration?

Comment: The CreateBasketServiceAction extends TransactionalServiceAction. Is inheritance an issue with @Autowire?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : not sure what you mean by proxied...is CreateBasketServiceAction proxied?

Comment: Possibly. Do you have any transaction management in that class? Do you have any aspects in play in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, the TransactionalServiceAction is indeed responsible for transaction management. I'm not sure about all the details on this one, but is there any specific things I need to take into account with regards to that?

Comment: Dao beans may not have been successfully instantiated due to failure to instantiate the Datasource bean.  This can happen if Datasource cannot connect to the database.  For example, password is wrong or database is down.